# OpenNI 2 OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, openni

I've been struggling with this for too much time. I am trying to install OpenNI 2 to make my kinect work with a Mac on OS X Mountain Lion.

I downloaded the package for OS X from http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk and and I ran the install.sh file with sudo privileges inside it, which did absolutely nothing more than to create an "OpenNIDevEnvironment" file in the same folder as the install file. In the Redist I see some libraries, which are not installed. I also took a look at the install.sh script. It's not supposed to copy anything!

Can anyone tell me how to proceed from this point onwards?

Answer (score 3):

i have the problem too.
try download
https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2
than go into the folder and do
"sudo make"

in my case, my new problem is "no device found".
but that could be the problem of Kinect Model 1473.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that first step appears to do nothing but there is more to it, this might have some answers: http://www.theworldneedsmoredreamers.net/using-openni-2-2-beta-on-os-x/